# Token addresses for DAI , USDC and WBTC for IUniswapV2Router02

Tags: solidity, ether, uniswap

I have searched a lot but maybe I am looking in the wrong places.

Please how can I get the token addresses for USDC , WBTC and DAI that work with Uniswap Router02 on mainnet and kovan.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kovan has its own etherscan at: https://kovan.etherscan.io

You can search for any token e.g. DAI: https://kovan.etherscan.io/token/0xc707fd5a456eec2609463f7fea79756356f0a754

Check this project out as well: https://github.com/bokkypoobah/WeenusTokenFaucet - It has a list of a few ERC20's that you can mint from their faucet. You can then add these to a Uniswap exchange using their factory and interact with your uniswap exchange.